# Why is my MinHeap sorting integers correctly but not my own class

Tags: c++, data-structures, priority-queue, heapsort

I made my own minHeap template which seems to sort integers perfectly fine, but when i try to sort my own class that i call Road it sorts about half of it correctly...

The Road class is defined as such: It has two integers called cityA and cityB as well as a double called length.

When comparing two roads A and B we say A is less than B is A's length member is smaller than B's length member OR if their lengths are equal and A contains the smallest integer in it's cities of all four cities (cityA and cityB in A and cityA and CityB in B).

Example: RoadA has cityA=4, cityB=5, length=6; and RoadB has cityA=1 cityB=9,length=2.  In this scenario RoadB is smaller because its length is smaller

Example2: RoadA has cityA=4, cityB=5, length=6; and RoadB has cityA=1 cityB=9,length=6.  In this scenario RoadB is smaller because its contains the city with the smallest integer (cityA=1).

I believe i have correctly implemented this in my road.cpp but my MinHeap but it seems to not be sorting the roads correctly.

I made a test case to exemplify its behavior, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include"minHeap.h"
#include"road.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    minHeap<Road> roadHeap(100);

    for(int i=0; i< 20; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j< 20; j++){
            Road *tempRoad = new Road();

            tempRoad->setCityA(i);
            tempRoad->setCityB(j);
            tempRoad->setLength(5);

            roadHeap.push(*tempRoad);

            delete tempRoad; //minHeap takes in a copy of the road so i can safely delete this
        }
    }

    while(!roadHeap.isEmpty()){
        cout << "<road>" << roadHeap.top().getCityA() << " " << roadHeap.top().getCityB() << " " << roadHeap.top().getLength() << "</road>" << endl;
        roadHeap.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What this SHOULD do is print out the roads i the format `<road> [cityA] [cityB] [length] </road> [newline]`

since they all get pushed to the minHeap it should order the roads and the output SHOULD look like this:

```
<road>0 1 5</road>
<road>0 2 5</road>
<road>0 3 5</road>
<road>0 4 5</road>
<road>0 5 5</road>
<road>0 6 5</road>
<road>0 7 5</road>
<road>0 8 5</road>
<road>0 9 5</road>
<road>0 10 5</road>
<road>0 11 5</road>
<road>0 12 5</road>
<road>0 13 5</road>
<road>0 14 5</road>
<road>0 15 5</road>
<road>0 16 5</road>
<road>0 17 5</road>
<road>0 18 5</road>
<road>0 19 5</road>
<road>1 2 5</road>
<road>1 3 5</road>
<road>1 4 5</road>
<road>1 5 5</road>
<road>1 6 5</road>
<road>1 7 5</road>
<road>1 8 5</road>
<road>1 9 5</road>
<road>1 10 5</road>
<road>1 11 5</road>
<road>1 12 5</road>
<road>1 13 5</road>
...
...
...
<road>18 19 5</road>
```

But INSTEAD my test program outputs the following:

```
<road>0 1 5</road>
<road>0 2 5</road>
<road>1 2 5</road>
<road>2 3 5</road>
<road>1 3 5</road>
<road>0 3 5</road>
<road>0 4 5</road>
<road>2 4 5</road>
<road>1 4 5</road>
<road>3 4 5</road>
<road>4 5 5</road>
<road>2 5 5</road>
<road>0 5 5</road>
<road>1 5 5</road>
<road>3 5 5</road>
<road>4 6 5</road>
<road>2 6 5</road>
<road>5 6 5</road>
<road>1 6 5</road>
<road>0 6 5</road>
<road>3 6 5</road>
<road>4 7 5</road>
<road>2 7 5</road>
<road>1 7 5</road>
<road>6 7 5</road>
<road>0 7 5</road>
<road>3 7 5</road>
<road>0 8 5</road>
<road>4 8 5</road>
<road>6 8 5</road>
<road>1 8 5</road>
<road>4 9 5</road>
<road>0 9 5</road>
<road>6 9 5</road>
<road>1 9 5</road>
<road>9 10 5</road>
<road>4 10 5</road>
<road>6 10 5</road>
<road>9 11 5</road>
<road>0 19 5</road>
<road>10 11 5</road>
<road>4 11 5</road>
<road>6 11 5</road>
<road>8 12 5</road>
<road>9 12 5</road>
<road>10 12 5</road>
<road>4 12 5</road>
<road>0 12 5</road>
<road>6 12 5</road>
<road>1 17 5</road>
<road>3 13 5</road>
<road>3 19 5</road>
<road>8 13 5</road>
<road>9 13 5</road>
<road>10 13 5</road>
<road>2 13 5</road>
<road>0 13 5</road>
<road>6 13 5</road>
<road>1 14 5</road>
<road>3 14 5</road>
<road>8 14 5</road>
<road>2 14 5</road>
<road>6 14 5</road>
<road>2 15 5</road>
<road>6 15 5</road>
<road>3 12 5</road>
<road>1 13 5</road>
<road>7 19 5</road>
<road>7 18 5</road>
<road>7 17 5</road>
<road>7 16 5</road>
<road>7 15 5</road>
<road>7 14 5</road>
<road>8 16 5</road>
<road>5 16 5</road>
<road>7 12 5</road>
<road>7 11 5</road>
<road>7 10 5</road>
<road>8 11 5</road>
<road>6 19 5</road>
<road>6 18 5</road>
<road>11 15 5</road>
<road>11 16 5</road>
<road>2 16 5</road>
<road>6 16 5</road>
<road>5 17 5</road>
<road>2 17 5</road>
<road>9 17 5</road>
<road>11 14 5</road>
<road>6 17 5</road>
<road>4 17 5</road>
<road>7 8 5</road>
<road>3 8 5</road>
<road>9 19 5</road>
<road>10 14 5</road>
<road>10 15 5</road>
<road>5 15 5</road>
<road>5 14 5</road>
<road>5 13 5</road>
<road>8 17 5</road>
<road>5 11 5</road>
<road>5 10 5</road>
<road>9 14 5</road>
<road>0 11 5</road>
<road>8 15 5</road>
<road>1 15 5</road>
<road>3 15 5</road>
<road>4 18 5</road>
<road>9 15 5</road>
<road>0 16 5</road>
<road>4 15 5</road>
<road>4 14 5</road>
<road>4 13 5</road>
<road>10 16 5</road>
<road>3 16 5</road>
<road>10 17 5</road>
<road>11 12 5</road>
<road>12 16 5</road>
<road>0 18 5</road>
<road>12 15 5</road>
<road>13 15 5</road>
<road>13 18 5</road>
<road>3 18 5</road>
<road>0 17 5</road>
<road>14 15 5</road>
<road>12 19 5</road>
<road>11 17 5</road>
<road>14 17 5</road>
<road>8 10 5</road>
<road>3 11 5</road>
<road>1 12 5</road>
<road>0 15 5</road>
<road>7 13 5</road>
<road>12 18 5</road>
<road>15 16 5</road>
<road>1 16 5</road>
<road>9 16 5</road>
<road>2 19 5</road>
<road>2 18 5</road>
<road>3 17 5</road>
<road>1 18 5</road>
<road>8 19 5</road>
<road>5 18 5</road>
<road>9 18 5</road>
<road>2 12 5</road>
<road>5 12 5</road>
<road>2 10 5</road>
<road>5 9 5</road>
<road>10 18 5</road>
<road>11 13 5</road>
<road>4 16 5</road>
<road>12 14 5</road>
<road>12 13 5</road>
<road>13 17 5</road>
<road>1 19 5</road>
<road>13 16 5</road>
<road>13 14 5</road>
<road>15 18 5</road>
<road>16 18 5</road>
<road>13 19 5</road>
<road>8 9 5</road>
<road>3 10 5</road>
<road>1 11 5</road>
<road>0 14 5</road>
<road>14 16 5</road>
<road>14 19 5</road>
<road>11 19 5</road>
<road>14 18 5</road>
<road>2 11 5</road>
<road>2 9 5</road>
<road>2 8 5</road>
<road>0 10 5</road>
<road>16 17 5</road>
<road>17 18 5</road>
<road>15 19 5</road>
<road>15 17 5</road>
<road>3 9 5</road>
<road>1 10 5</road>
<road>11 18 5</road>
<road>12 17 5</road>
<road>5 8 5</road>
<road>5 7 5</road>
<road>10 19 5</road>
<road>16 19 5</road>
<road>7 9 5</road>
<road>8 18 5</road>
<road>4 19 5</road>
<road>17 19 5</road>
<road>5 19 5</road>
<road>18 19 5</road>
```

RELEVANT CODE:

Here is my road.h:

```
#ifndef ROAD_H
#define ROAD_H

class Road{

public:

    Road();
    void setCityA(int);
    const int getCityA() const;

    void setCityB(int);
    const int getCityB() const;

    void setLength(double);
    const double getLength() const;

    friend bool operator<(const Road&, const Road&);
    friend bool operator>(const Road&, const Road&);
    friend bool operator>=(const Road&, const Road&);
    friend bool operator<=(const Road&, const Road&);

    Road *nextRoad;

private:
    int cityA;
    int cityB;
    double length;
};

#endif
```

Here is my road.cpp:

```
#include"road.h"

Road::Road(){
    nextRoad = 0;
}

void Road::setCityA(int x){
    this->cityA = x;
}

const int Road::getCityA() const{
    return this->cityA;
}

void Road::setCityB(int x){
    this->cityB = x;
}

const int Road::getCityB() const{
    return this->cityB;
}

void Road::setLength(double x){
    this->length = x;
}

const double Road::getLength() const{
    return this->length;
}

bool operator<(const Road &lhs, const Road &rhs)
{

    if(lhs.getLength() < rhs.getLength()) return 1;
    else if( (lhs.getLength() == rhs.getLength()) && (lhs.getCityA() < rhs.getCityA()) && (lhs.getCityA() < rhs.getCityB()) ) return 1;
    else if( (lhs.getLength() == rhs.getLength()) && (lhs.getCityB() < rhs.getCityA()) && (lhs.getCityB() < rhs.getCityB()) ) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

bool operator>(const Road &lhs, const Road &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.getLength() > rhs.getLength()) return 1;
    else if( (lhs.getLength() == rhs.getLength()) && (lhs.getCityA() > rhs.getCityA()) && (lhs.getCityA() > rhs.getCityB()) ) return 1;
    else if( (lhs.getLength() == rhs.getLength()) && (lhs.getCityB() > rhs.getCityA()) && (lhs.getCityB() > rhs.getCityB()) ) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

bool operator<=(const Road &lhs, const Road &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.getLength() < rhs.getLength()) return 1;
    else if( (lhs.getLength() == rhs.getLength()) && (lhs.getCityA() < rhs.getCityA()) && (lhs.getCityA() < rhs.getCityB()) ) return 1;
    else if( (lhs.getLength() == rhs.getLength()) && (lhs.getCityB() < rhs.getCityA()) && (lhs.getCityB() < rhs.getCityB()) ) return 1;
    else return 0;;
}
bool operator>=(const Road &lhs, const Road &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.getLength() > rhs.getLength()) return 1;
    else if( (lhs.getLength() == rhs.getLength()) && (lhs.getCityA() > rhs.getCityA()) && (lhs.getCityA() > rhs.getCityB()) ) return 1;
    else if( (lhs.getLength() == rhs.getLength()) && (lhs.getCityB() > rhs.getCityA()) && (lhs.getCityB() > rhs.getCityB()) ) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Here is my minHeap.h (which also includes it's implementation):

```
#ifndef MIN_HEAP
#define MIN_HEAP

template<class T>
class minHeap{

public:
    minHeap(int);
    void push(const T&);
    void pop();
    T top();
    void doubleHeapCap();
    bool isEmpty();
    T *heap;
    int heapSize;
    int capacity;

};

template<class T>
minHeap<T>::minHeap(int theCapacity = 10){

    if(theCapacity < 1) throw "Capacity must be >=1.";
    capacity = theCapacity;
    heapSize = 0;
    heap = new T[capacity + 1]; //heap [0] is not used

}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::push(const T& e){
//inserts e into min heap
    if(heapSize == capacity){ //doubles capacity if Heap is too small
        this->doubleHeapCap();
        this->capacity *=2;
    }

    int currentNode = ++heapSize;

    while(currentNode != 1 && heap[currentNode/2] > e){
        //bubble up node
        heap[currentNode] = heap[currentNode/2]; //moves parent down
        currentNode /= 2; //moves current node
    }

    heap[currentNode] = e;

}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::pop(){
//Deletes smallest element from heap and restructures heap
    if(isEmpty()) throw "Heap is empty. Cannot delete.";

    //deelt smallest element
    heap[1].~T();

    //remove last element from heap
    T lastE = heap[heapSize--];

    //trickle down to restructure heap
    int currentNode = 1; //root of heap
    int child = 2; // first child of heap

    while(child <= heapSize){

        //set child to smaller child of currentNode
        if(child < heapSize && heap[child] > heap[child+1]) child++;

        //can we put lastE in currenNode?
        if(lastE <= heap[child]) break; //yes we can

        //no we can't, Obama
        heap[currentNode] = heap[child]; //move child up
        currentNode = child; child *= 2; // move a level down
    }

    //after you finally find one, place the node in the corrent position
    heap[currentNode] = lastE;
}

template<class T>
T minHeap<T>::top(){
    return heap[1];
}

template<class T>
bool minHeap<T>::isEmpty(){
//says whether or not hear is empty
    if(heapSize == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::doubleHeapCap(){

    int newCapacity = (this->capacity)*2;
    T *temp;
    T *newHeap;

    //create a new heap with twic the size
    newHeap = new T[newCapacity + 1];

    //copy elements over
    for(int i=0; i<=capacity; i++){
        newHeap[i] = this->heap[i];
    }

    //delete the old heap
    temp = heap;
    heap = newHeap;
    newHeap = 0;

    delete[] temp;
}
#endif
```

Please note that that operators for less and or equal to and greater than or equal to are the same as less than and greater than, respectively, i defined them this way just because my minHeap uses both types of operators, but in this case there are no two roads that are equal (i filter out any roads that could be equal).

Thanks for the help, any input is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not implement >= in terms of not < (and same for > and <=) to save duplicated some logic.

Comment: heap[1].~T(); I'm pretty sure this is wrong. As you created the heap with new[], it is not possible to delete individual elements in this way.

Comment: @Neil Kirk's first comment - That actually seems like a great idea, but i don't think thats what is causing this issue unfortunately. The reason i make <= and >= the same as their non-equal-to partners is because my minHeap uses the equal-to versions for other data types but for roads there is only greater than or less than, there are no equal roads.

Comment: @NeilKirk - Hmmm That may be it, how do you suggest going about solving that issue?  how would to implement a destructor that would fully remove the road from the heap?

Comment: If you need an array of dynamic length to implement your heap, use `std::vector` instead of re-implementing it.

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. if !(a < b) and !(b < a) then should be a == b

Comment: @Casey - This is for a data structures class for school, the teacher does not allow us to use STL libraries, this is why i had to make a priority queue in the first place...

Comment: @NeilKirk - The program does processing on the input of roads, before it pushes them to the heap. As a result i should never have two roads that are equal (none can have the same cities and the same length).

Comment: The definition of a < b, or, a == b, does not depend on what actual values of a and b you may have in a particular scenario. Please define them correctly and if that logic does not end up being used, better it is there correctly in case if it needed in the future.

Comment: Take two roads that are mis-ordered in your output and run them through your comparison function. What do you get?

Comment: Why doesn't doubleHeapCap function double this->capacity itself? You even calculate the new capacity but don't store it.

Comment: @NeilKirk - you are correct. I will implement <= and >= as not > and not <. But how should i go about fixing my minHeap not sorting the roads correctly?

Comment: I would not bother to delete the individual element as you never decrease the capacity of your heap anyway. When you push back, eventually the dead nodes will be reused with new data (I think).

Comment: @NeilKirk - wow that is a bug, i will change that right now to make the capacity updated.

Comment: @NeilKirk - i'm sorry i am confused what you mean by "not bother deleting te individual element" and "eventually the dead nodes will be reused with new data"

Comment: How should "0 1 5" and "0 2 5" be ordered? Because (IIRC) you have both !("0 1 5" < "0 2 5") and !("0 2 5" < "0 1 5"). Your "<" isn't a total ordering, which would be why you can't sort with it.

Comment: Remove line heap[1].~T(). Say you pop from your heap, and then you push again. Will the new element, be copied into the position of the old element, you wished to delete?

Comment: Take note you also double the capacity in the push function. This should be moved to the double function.

Comment: @Casey - "0 1 5" should be less than "0 2 5" because their lengths are equal but "0 1 5" has the smallest city that isn't in "0 2 5" (city 1).

Comment: @user0123 You need to fix your "<" then, because that's not how it's comparing.

Comment: "When comparing two roads A and B we say A is less than B is A's length member is smaller than B's length member OR if A contains the smallest integer in it's cities of all four cities (cityA and cityB in A and cityA and CityB in B)." I'm not sure I understand this. Does this mean a road my be less than another if it has a longer length but the lowest city number?

Comment: @NeilKirk - I am sorry, i am still confused. My impresssion was that heap[1].~T() cause the element to be deleted from the heap.

When you push the element is compared to the last element of the heap, then if it is smaller they trade places, and so on up the tree. Is something wrong with this?

Comment: @NeilKirk - I am sorry, i will change that in the post. In order for the second comparison to take place (the one that compares their roads) their lengths must be equal.

Comment: Calling the destructor manually ~T() must only be used with placement new which is an advanced topic. Is it correct than when popping from the heap, and then pushing the heap back up to capacity, elements of the heap array will be reused?

Comment: @Casey - I don't see what is wrong with the < operator. It checks if their lengths are the same, if they are it checks if the left-hand-sides cityA is smaller than both the cities in the right-hand-side, if it is then we know the lhs has the smallest city, then it does the same with the lhs's cityB

Comment: @NeilKirk - what do you mean by  "pushing the heap back up to capacity"? Are you asking about the limits of the heaps capacity?

Sorry for not understanding your question, I am kind of a novice at this stuff.

Comment: I am talking about your push and pop functions. Say you have 10 elements in your heap array. When you call pop, you have 9 used elements and one unused one. When you call push, you have 10 used elements again, therefore the one you "deleted" in pop is reused. This is correct?

Comment: @NeilKirk - I believe this is how the minHeap is supposed to work. Are you suggesting that my code doesn't work like that?

the element that gets pushed is stored into at array[heapsize+1] because the heapsize increases by one when you push. After it get stored the push function does comparisons to percolate the elements place in the array up to where it needs to be.

Comment: Yes that is good. What I am saying is, you are not actually "deleting" the element when you pop it. It is simply laying unused/inactive in your array, and may be used again in the future. In that case, you don't need to delete anything. In fact, it's wrong to delete the element or call its destructor, because if you use a deleted or destructed element again, that is undefined behavior.

Comment: @NeilKirk - ahh i see what you are saying. So how should i go about fixing this isue? I need to get the top element away from the top somehow....

Comment: If your current pop logic works then it is fine, just remove the ~T(). Imagine you have a linear data structure of 10 elements. When you pop an element, you just need to update the size variable of the data structure to 9. Element 10 is still there, it is just ignored. When you push back on the data structure, size increases to 10 and the old element at position 10 has copied onto it the new value. Does that make sense? Let's say, element 10 was pretend-deleted, as far the user of the data structure is concerned, but it wasn't really deleted inside.

Comment: But when i pop i need to make the element at position 1 no longer in that positon, right? Why do i feel like by taking away heap[1].~T() the element at position 1 will just sit there and the next time i call top() it will give me the same element...

Comment: I don't know what should be there, but I do know ~T() does not make a difference to what is returned by top. Top only returns the element at position 1. If you don't copy a valid element to position 1 in your pop function, then what should top return? Either an old element or a deleted element. Both are wrong..

Comment: Btw I know this is the least of your worries, but your heap is missing a destructor that deletes the array.

Answer (score 0):

With your > operator road(0,8,5) > road (2,7,5) because 8>2 & 8>7

Comment: This should work fine also, but what is wrong with what i have right now?

also what libraries would i need to include to use min and max? I am not allowed to use anything from STL in this project

Comment: min and max are standard std functions in <algorithm> header I believe. Please, please, remember this! It's common in these classes you have arbitrary restrictions on what you can use. I can understand, it's to make you understand what happens inside. But often how to properly use the STL data structures, which are very powerful, is not properly covered. In a real world project, you would use vector instead of array in your heap and it would make your code simpler and less bug-prone.

Comment: unfortunately <algorithms> is apart of the STL:( 

Why does my own < operator not work? to me it seems perfectly logical, and how should i go about fixing it if it is broken?